# What are the limitations of HSQLDB for java desktop application?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, hsqldb

I am using MySQL for data storage/retrival in my java desktop application but now i am going to create another version of my application that will support/use HSQLDB for data storage/retrival. Is there any restriction on creating number of databases in HSQLDB ? What can be the other major limitations of using HSQLDB ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the major limitations in the faq - [Reliability, Performance and Deployment](http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlFAQ.html)